# How to get attribute of a json data in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, attributes

I have sample json data as below

```
[{"@attributes":{"id":"F11D-6T47"},"Name":{"FirstName":"Praveen",
"MiddleName":{},"LastName":"Indukuri","NameSuffix":{}},
"DateOfBirth":{"Day":"31","Month":"08","Year":"1990"},"Phone":"4047549241",
"SSN":"670249778","DriversLicenseNumber":"I532671903110",
"Address":{"Line1":"144 Towey Trai","Line2":{},"Line3":{},
"City":"Woodstock","State":"Georgia","Zip":"30188","County":{},
"Latitude":"0","Longitude":"0"}},{"@attributes":{"id":"F11D-6T47"},
"Name":{"FirstName":"Praveen","MiddleName":{},"LastName":"Indukuri",
"NameSuffix":{}},"DateOfBirth":{"Day":"31","Month":"08","Year":"1990"},
"Phone":"4047549241","SSN":"670249778","DriversLicenseNumber":"I532671903110",
"Address":{"Line1":"144 Towey Trai","Line2":{},"Line3":{},
"City":"Woodstock","State":"Georgia","Zip":"30188",
"County":{},"Latitude":"0","Longitude":"0"}}]
```

I want to get all the `id` valued in @attributes for the enitre array using php.

Comment: Thanku Paul Crovella.but  i want to get attributes value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign your json to a variable let's say $json and decode it to get a php array.

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
// array to store the ids.
$ids = array();
foreach($array as $item) {
   $attributes = $item['@attributes'];
   array_push($ids, $attributes['id']);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanku Mubhaskar...its working

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I could help.